# Properties of Frobenius matrix and decomposability

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $D$ is Frobenius matrix, is there any relationship of the matrix being Frobenius matrix with $D$ being $D = (A-I)B^{-1}$ where $A$ is non-negative square matrix?

Also, how is Frobenius matrix used?

Comment: You can read a lot about frobenius matrix in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_matrix